# calculating the area in polar coördinates

Tags: area, polar-coordinates, bounds-of-integration

I have difficulties calculating the area and setting the right boundaries of the following polar coördinates:

$$r=2(1+cos(\theta) ) $$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is $a$, the polar angle (generally referred as) $\theta$?

Comment: yes it is, i did not know how to type it

Comment: use $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac12 r^2 d\theta$

Comment: I guess i know what i did wrong. I calculated it correctly and had an answer of $$ 3pi $$. But I think it must be $$3pi * 2$$ because it is above and below the x-axis, or I am mistaken myself?

Comment: Since you haven't shown the detailed steps of your work we can only guess where you made your error. There are various ways you could make a mistake by a factor of $2$ in a problem like this.

Comment: these are the steps @DavidK :$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}0.5*(2(1+cos(x))^2)dx$$

$$\int(1+cos(x))^2$$
$$\int1+2cos(x) + cos(x)^2 $$
$$x+2sin(x)+\cfrac 1 {2} x +\cfrac {sin(2x)} {4}$$
$$ \cfrac 3 {2}x +2sin(x)+ \cfrac {sin(2x)} {4}$$

filling in the boundaries 2pi and 0

$$ \cfrac 3 {2}*2\pi +2sin(2\pi)+ \cfrac {sin(2*2\pi)} {4} - (\cfrac 3 {2}*0 +2sin(0)+ \cfrac {sin(2*0)} {4})$$

Comment: Looks like you only squared part of your r @wouterlommerse

Comment: @randomgirl I see now thanks a lot!

Comment: It generally works out better (and I think is probably easier for you too) to edit the question in order to add information rather than putting a lot of formulas in comments. But it looks like the error has been identified now.

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$\theta\mapsto r(\theta):=2(1+\cos\theta)$$
does not define an area per se. Now this function is $2\pi$-periodic, and graphing the curve
$$\gamma:\quad\theta\mapsto\bigl(x(\theta),y(\theta)\bigr)=r(\theta)\,(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\qquad(-\pi\leq\theta\leq\pi)$$
we obtain a "loop with an indent" enclosing a certain shape $A$, whereby $\gamma$ is astroidal with respect to the origin. The area of $A$ then can be calculated with the formula
$${\rm area}(A)={1\over2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}r^2(\theta)\>d\theta=6\pi\ .$$